# Create bit map font file from true type font

Tags: java

I it possible to create a bit map font file from a true type font using java ?

Thanks

Comment: TrueType fonts can be bitmap fonts already. What you mean by "bitmap font"? A big bitmap with all the glyphs of a given TrueType font rendered on it?

Comment: Ok, I have a true type font file and I want to append some characters to this font file progammatically. Then output a range of different font created from the true type font file. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this in J2ME polish -

Comment: <taskdef name="bmfcreate" 
      classname="de.enough.polish.font.BmfCreationTask" 
      classpath="${polish.home}/lib/enough-j2mepolish-build.jar" />
     <target name="convertfonts">
             <bmfcreate 
             color="#ff0" 
             size="1" 
             antialiased="true"
             characterSpacing="3" 
             input="se/fonts/240w400h/ari_____.ttf"
             output="st.bmf"></bmfcreate>
     </target>